# TYPO3 404 Error handling

Tags: error-handling, typo3, typoscript

There are a lot of tutorials about error 404 handling and different solutions.

If I'm using TYPO3 6.1, Fluid/Extbase and RealURL, what is the best way to make an Error 404/500 handler that uses the page Uid = 13 (error/notfound/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an error 500, TYPO3 will not be able to handle it since it is "crashed". For 404 handling you will see a list of possibilites in the install tool, section [pageNotFound_handling].

The most straight-forward way for a website with one language is to enter an absolute URL to the [pageNotFound_handling] field. The URL could point to a TYPO3 page or a static HTML site. TYPO3 will not redirect to this page, but output this page and send the proper 404 status.

Comment: Hi Lorenz, yes i have the [pageNotFound_handling] and i have added this error/Fejl404 to it, when i type in a pagename that i know is not there, i get a blank page, its not showing me the Fejl404 page in the folder error.

Comment: You either need to give an absolute path on the server or an absolute URL as described in this setting.

Comment: Thanks pgampe, I just added "absolute URL" to my answer.